# My Rails apps all suddenly became read-only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod

I was working on my rails app, left it for a while, came back, and tried to restart my server. In response, I got back this error:

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/user/app/log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
```

I have no idea what I could have done to cause this. I never even touched my log directory. I tried to run `chmod 0666 /home/user/app/log/development.log` and then various other chmod commands, like `chmod 0664` and `chmod 777`. Each time I got back:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/home/user/app/log/development.log’: Read-only file system
```

but I always got back the same error from `rails s`.

Then I gave up and switched to a different app I'm working on, but after running `rails s` for that app, I got back basically the same error:

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/user/sweat/log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
```

What is going on? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

**UPDATE**

Running `sudo chmod 777 -R log` gives me back this:

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/user/1: No such file or directory
chmod: changing permissions of ‘log’: Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of ‘log/development.log’: Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of ‘log/.keep’: Read-only file system
```

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the /log directory... Does the file actually exist?

Comment: @BradWerth Yes, both apps have /log/development.log files.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Linux!
try this => **cd home/user/app**
*then*     => **sudo chmod 777 -R log**

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I ran this, but I got back an error, which I added to my question.

Comment: Did you open app directory in terminal?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Yes, I was in the correct directory.